# Rosh HaShana greeting - L'Shana Tova Tikosaivu - V'chain L'Mar

Tags: halacha, blessing, rosh-hashanah-new-year, evening-night

[Rama Orach Chaim 582:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=111) says in the name of the Tur that the Minhag is to wish one another on the evening of Rosh HaShana L'Shana Tova Tikosaiv. Is there a source that says that people should answer V'Chain L'Mar? Or is it more appropriate to respond L'Shana Tova Tikosaiv? (sources)

Comment: Saying V'chain l'mar would certainly make things easier! But the Rema gives this as the greeting, I'm assuming mitzad derech eretz you should return the bracha the same way you got it, or at least be makdim to say before the other person does. But interesting question none the less.

Comment: The response of "vechen lemar" is, if I remember, found in the last chapter of Megilah

Comment: Someone seriously replied "vechen lemotuk" ("and the same to the sweet") to me on the grounds that "mar" also means "bitter".

Answer (score 2):

[Nitei Gavriel Rosh HaShana 27:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46450&st=&pgnum=207) - One may answer either L'Shana Tova or Gam Atta.

Comment: Interesting I saw a different Nitei Gavreil which said one can say vchain lomar and gam atem